# Paypal transaction type

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to change the paypal transaction type from product/services to  gift or something else. But did not find how to do that.

I am using the form method(most basic). Which of the setting do i need to do this , or the hidden parameter which should be passed in the input field for changing the transaction type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you are referring to the cmd variable for your form. 
For ex. if you want to use a simple buy now button you can use _xclick value for cmd variable.

Check this out: [List of PayPal HTML variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Answer (score 0):

PayPal's Website Payments Standard is designed to support merchants collecting payments in exchange for goods or services. While there is a specialization of the flow for donations (see e.g. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_pps-donateButton/), WPS does not provide access to PayPal's (no-fee) peer-to-peer payments functionality (such as for sending gifts, payments for splitting bills, etc).